# Changing params in route

Tags: angular, routes

I'm working on a project where I need two languages for GUI. I've got LangService which provides phrases for every component. Every component fetches the active language based on current route and request phrases from LangService.

My question is... I need to have my "languages switch" inside my navbar, which is in the main "app.component". Navbar is always at the top, so I have access to it from every component. I want to be able to click the button in the navbar and change current route (change current language). How is it possible?
I thought there is a way to change `route.params`. That Way I would change `route.params['lang'] = 'EN'`;

AppComponent.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{ title }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li *ngFor="let lang of langs"><a (click)="changeLanguage()">{{ lang }}</a></li>
        </ol>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

AppComponent.ts (How I thought it would work):

```
export class AppComponent {  
  changeLanguage() {
    // catch the route params lang
    // change route params
    // set new route
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use navigation to navigate to the same route with a different parameter. So, if you are in /component/subroute/en and switch to Spanish, use router.navigate with a path to /component/subroute/es.

The routing documentation (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters) contains an example for listening to changing route parameters, which you will need to do as the component won't be reloaded, because the actual route does not change, merely the parameter.